# confirm and test if data receiving from server on android studio

Tags: android, server

I have an application that relies mostly on communication with the server ... The application contains a book that the customer can buy parts of it and there are several other things (such as small game and coins and in_app_billing). The problem is that in the Internet is not good will happen to communicate with The server. In your opinion what is the solution to this problem, so how can I make sure that the information has arrived and in case you did not arrive `to return the ball until the information arrives` or for example after 30 seconds of the attempt showed him a message that it is impossible to reach Network.

using:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(),URL insertUserUrl = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection result;
InputStreamReader resultStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(insertConnection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader resultReader = new BufferedReader(resultStreamReader);
result = resultReader.readLine();
```

Please reply and thank you very much

Comment: Try and study logcat, it will help you learn to debug your code https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: Thanks, but I do not mean that, I just want to make sure if I get data from the server